# Why am I not getting drop down menu in my cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Below is the cshtml code to display AddBooking view and I am not getting drop down in RoomType below.

```
@model Booking
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager


@{
    var rooms = ViewData["RoomTypes"] as List<SelectListItem>;
}


<h1>Add Booking</h1>
<hr />

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form asp-action="AddBooking" method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" claclass="text-danger"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ChecKIn" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ChecKIn" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ChecKIn" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label asp-for="CheckOut" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CheckOut" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CheckOut" class="text-danger"></span>
                
                </div>
                
//this id is the part where the dropdown is supposed to happen
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="RoomType" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="RoomTypeId" asp-items="rooms" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="NumberOfRooms" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="NumberOfRooms" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfRooms" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">BookRoom</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
  }
```

I am looking for where I am making a mistake as it is not showing the dropdown options and the type of room should be accessed from database and should be able to display in dropdown, and how to set availability of rooms in room table false once we book the room from bOoking view?

Here is the link of github if you need more details:

link=https://github.com/meprigesh/HotelReservationwithsec.git

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the related server side code where you assign `ViewData["RoomTypes"]`. Please provide enough detail so we know what exactly is being assigned to the ViewData.

Comment: Also, if you have a question about how to set the availability of rooms, please open a separate question. This site expects **one** question per post. You'll want to provide the related code in your new question that demonstrates your best attempt at setting the availability of rooms, and then explain at what point in your code you aren't getting the result you expect.

Comment: Hi @Prigesh Basnet, how do you set value for rooms in `asp-items="rooms"`? From your shared github repo I cannot see view named `AddBooking ` and your BookingController does not contains any related code about this.

Comment: Hey @Rena I have updated my code in the git repo please check again I am new to programming so I probably have forgotten to push the code it will be grate help if you can pin down what am I misiing.

Comment: Hi @PrigeshBasnet, I check your git repo again, yes now it contains AddBooking action and view. But I haven't see you configure the value for the `ViewData["RoomTypes"] ` in your `AddBooking` action. If you not configure the value it will not display in dropdown... From your description, you want to access database to display the dropdown, so you do not know how to do?

Comment: @Rena i tried to do it few times but it didin't work so i have to say i do bot know how to  use properly so can you give me suggesstion where and how i can define ViewData["RoomTypes"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need configure `ViewData["RoomTypes"]` in `AddBooking` action like below to populate the dropdown:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class BookingController : Controller
{
    private readonly HotelReservationContext context;
    public BookingController(HotelReservationContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddBooking()
    {
        ViewData["RoomTypes"] = context.RoomTypes.Select(
                                    c => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Value = c.RoomTypeId.ToString(),
                                        Text = c.TypeOfRoom
                                    }).ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```